# Is it possible to get the compiler to exit early, failing the build, if a compile time warning is raised?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I find the compile time warnings very useful, but I can occasionally miss them, especially if it's on a pull request where the tests are running on a CI server.

Ideally I would specify something in the project mix file that would make the compiler more strict.

I want to this to be in effect for all mix tasks, and I do not want to have to pass the flag to the command, as this is easy to forget.

For example with a project with a compiler warning, this command should fail

```
mix clean && mix compile
```

As should this one

```
mix clean && mix test
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible to some extent. There is a flag `--warnings-as-errors` in `elixirc` command.

```
☁  hello_elixir [master] ⚡ elixirc
Usage: elixirc [elixir switches] [compiler switches] [.ex files]

  -o               The directory to output compiled files
  --no-docs        Do not attach documentation to compiled modules
  --no-debug-info  Do not attach debug info to compiled modules
  --ignore-module-conflict
  --warnings-as-errors Treat warnings as errors and return non-zero exit code
  --verbose        Print informational messages.

** Options given after -- are passed down to the executed code
** Options can be passed to the erlang runtime using ELIXIR_ERL_OPTIONS
** Options can be passed to the erlang compiler using ERL_COMPILER_OPTIONS
```

For a module like this, with a warning:

```
defmodule Useless do
  defp another_userless, do: nil
end
```

When you compile without the flag:

```
☁  01_language [master] ⚡ elixirc useless.ex
useless.ex:2: warning: function another_userless/0 is unused
☁  01_language [master] ⚡ echo $?
0
```

You get the return code as **0**.

But when you compile with the flag `--warnings-as-errors`, it returns an exit code of **1**.

```
☁  01_language [master] ⚡ elixirc --warnings-as-errors useless.ex
useless.ex:1: warning: redefining module Useless
useless.ex:2: warning: function another_userless/0 is unused
☁  01_language [master] ⚡ echo $?
1
```

You can use this return code in your compile script for break the build process.

Answer (score 13):

In your `mix.exs`:

```
def project do
  [...,
   aliases: aliases]
end

defp aliases do
  ["compile": ["compile --warnings-as-errors"]]
end
```

Then `mix compile` will pass `--warnings-as-errors` to the `compile.elixir` subtask.

This also works for `mix test` since it runs the `compile` task implicitly.

---

If you don't add an alias, you can still run `mix compile --warnings-as-errors` and it will do what you expect, but `mix test --warnings-as-errors` will not do what you expect, since the flag does not reach the `compile.elixir` task.

Comment: You may also use `elixirc_options: [warnings_as_errors: true]`.

Comment: If you're using mix to compile Erlang code, you'll need `erlc_options: [:warnings_as_errors]`

Answer (score 0):

I like Michael Stalker's solution [here](https://blog.rentpathcode.com/elixir-warnings-as-errors-sometimes-f5a8d2c96b15).

Treating warnings as errors *always* can get annoying during TDD, where you might be rapidly refactoring code while running tests.

Instead, you can make the `--warnings-as-errors` flag conditional on your Mix env like this:

```
defmodule SomeProject.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      elixirc_options: [
        warnings_as_errors: treat_warnings_as_errors?(Mix.env())
      ]
      # ...
    ]
  end

  defp treat_warnings_as_errors?(:test), do: false
  defp treat_warnings_as_errors?(_), do: true
end
```

Warnings will go ignored when testing, but not for a `dev` or `prod` compilation.