# Changing elixir's compiler settings to be more strict

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I just spent a lot of time hunting down a bug in Phoenix (1.3).  The problem was in `/my_app/content/post.ex`, in a function called `create_item/1`.  I compiled several times, but this function was not working correctly.

Finally I discovered that there was another function `create_item/1` in the same file (a few hundred lines down), and that was the function that was being called.

As it turned out, this was a warning that the compiler was printing to `iex`, but running anyway.  Is there any way to adjust the compiler's settings so that it does not allow running with warnings like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the compiler to exit early, failing the build, if a compile time warning is raised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982577/is-it-possible-to-get-the-compiler-to-exit-early-failing-the-build-if-a-compil)

Comment: I assume you mean to say:  `so that it does NOT allow running with warnings like this?`

Comment: @KevinJohnson Yes, just changed that