# How to ignore compilation warnings when running phoenix server

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to run phoenix server from the command line with `iex -S mix phx.server` but I keep getting warnings on compilation about unused variables.

`Compilation failed due to warnings while using the --warnings-as-errors option`

I don't care about these warnings as i am in the middle of development and these vars will eventually be used or tossed out.  I have tried passing `-h` and other sensible options, but none of them work and I can't find anything in the docs about how to get `phx.server` to pass or override options to the compiler.

I've seen these docs and they haven't helped

- https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Run.html
- https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Server.html

I have tried passing the `--no-compile` option but this is a no-go since it leaves me unable to recompile during development.  I am currently using `IO.inspect` to call the vars and this seems to be "good enough" for me to pass the unused vars check, but I would rather be able to disable this flag in the compiler rather than littering my code with `IO.inspect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `mix compile --warnings-as-errors=false` first, then you can run `iex -S mix phx.server` without issues as it will already be compiled and should just start up.

Answer (score 9):

The error message is pretty clear on that:

> Compilation failed due to warnings while using the `--warnings-as-errors` option

You have this specific flag enabled on the compiler, it returns a non-zero exit code on warnings. Since you're not passing the option manually in the command-line, it's possible that it's being:

- Set via an `ENV` variable (possibly by an Elixir version manager)
- Being passed in a `mix` alias or task
- **But most probably it's hardcoded in your `Mixfile`** under `elixirc_options`. You can disable it like this:

  ```ex
  # mix.exs
  elixirc_options: [warnings_as_errors: false]
  ```

---

On a side note, to get help on compiler options, you should use `elixirc`:

```
± % elixirc --help
Usage: elixirc [elixir switches] [compiler switches] [.ex files]

  -o                        The directory to output compiled files

  --help, -h                Prints this message and exits
  --ignore-module-conflict  Does not emit warnings if a module was previously defined
  --no-debug-info           Does not attach debug info to compiled modules
  --no-docs                 Does not attach documentation to compiled modules
  --verbose                 Prints compilation status
  --version, -v             Prints Elixir version and exits
  --warnings-as-errors      Treats warnings as errors and return non-zero exit code

** Options given after -- are passed down to the executed code
** Options can be passed to the Erlang runtime using ELIXIR_ERL_OPTIONS
** Options can be passed to the Erlang compiler using ERL_COMPILER_OPTIONS
```

---

<sup>*Also see: [Get the compiler to exit if a compile-time warning is raised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31985849/1533054)*</sup>

Comment: adding `elixirc_options: [warnings_as_errors: false]` to `project/0` in `mix.exs` has no effect.

Comment: I understand why it's happening.  I need to know how to turn it off.

Comment: Then there's probably an env variable or mix alias that's passing it as a flag. Take a look at the env flags exported by your elixir version manager and all tasks/aliases defined by your application.